# Fixed height container div, flexible height content div

Tags: html, css

I have a html code like this:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="content">
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
```

div#container's height is fixed (e.g 800px).
div#footer and div#header's size are not known at the beginning (to be set via Javascript).

I want div#content to take up 100% of the remaining height.

Can it be done using CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of functionality you can use **display:table** for this. Write like this:

```
.container{
    display:table;
    height:800px;
    width:100%;
}
.container > div{
    display:table-row;
}
.header{background:red; height:100px;}

.content{background:blue}

.footer{background:green; height:100px;}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/Rvbk4/

Note: it's work till IE8 & above.

Comment: Using these CSS rules, is there a way to set the header and footer's height equal to their content instead of some certain pixel values (you set 100px here)? If I remove height:100px, their height will be larger than their content's height. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can not set the footer height (as you wrote)
try this:

```
#container{
    background : red;
    height:800px;
    min-height:800px
}
#header{
    background : blue;
}
#content{
    background : yellow;
    height:100%
}
#footer{
    background : green;
    //position:absolute;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

and the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AJtxy/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the height of other divs with javascript, you can use jquery to get the height of the window, subtract the heights of the other 2 divs and voila, you are left with the correct amount...
This should help give you an idea
  http://api.jquery.com/height/